# Subir Imagen desde Front en Angular hasta Back en Laravel

Tags: html, laravel, angular, angular10

Desde hace varios días vengo intentando enviar una imagen desde Angular para que la misma se almacene en el Storage de Laravel.
Buscando encontré esta forma de hacerlo.

.component.html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="upload()">
   <label>Nombre</label>
   <input type="file" accept="image/*" (change)="seleccionarArchivo($event)">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Subir Archivo</button>
</form>
```

.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm, ReactiveFormsModule}                        from '@angular/forms';
import {FormControl,FormGroup,Validators}                                from '@angular/forms';
import { Post} from 'src/app/models/post';
import { ProcedimientosService } from 'src/app/services/procedimientos.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-nuevo',
  templateUrl: './nuevo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nuevo.component.css']
})
export class NuevoComponent implements OnInit {

 

  public archivo={
     nombreArchivo:null,
     base64textString:null
   };

  constructor(
    private _procedimientosService: ProcedimientosService
  ) { }

  public newPostForm = new FormGroup({
      imagePost: new FormControl('',Validators.required)
  })

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }


  

   seleccionarArchivo(event){
    var files=event.target.files;
    var file=files[0];
    this.archivo.nombreArchivo=file.name;
    if(file && files)    {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload=this._handleReaderLoader.bind(this);  
      reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    }
   }
   _handleReaderLoader(readerEvent){
     var binaryString=readerEvent.target.result;
     this.archivo.base64textString=btoa(binaryString);
   }

   upload(){
     console.log(this.archivo);
     this._procedimientosService.uploadFile(this.archivo).subscribe(
       response=>{
         if(response.status="success")
         {
           console.log(response);
           alert('Subido correctamente');
         }
       },
       error=>{
         console.log(<any>error)
       }
     );
   }
}
```

.component.service.ts

```
uploadFile(archivo):Observable<any>{
  let json=JSON.stringify(archivo);
  let params = "json="+json;
  console.log(params);
  let headers=new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded').set('Accept','*/*');
  return this._http.post(this.url+'add-image-post-prueba',params,{headers: headers});
}
```

Controller.php

```
public function addImageprueba(Request $request){
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
        
        $json=$request->input('json',null);
        $params_array=json_decode($json,true); 
        $archivo=$params_array['base64textString'];
        $archivo=base64_decode($archivo); 
        $image_path=$params_array['nombreArchivo'];
        \Storage::disk('images')->put($image_path, $archivo);
        $data=array(
               'image'=>$request, 
               'status'=>'success'
           );
           return response()->json($data,200);
    }
```

El resultado de todo esto es, que el archivo se guarda, respetando el nombre, pero no puedo abrirlo como imagen. Si comparo el tamaño del archivo, antes y después de subir noto que se pierden algunos KB, (137 contra 140), y si en propiedades, voy a detalles, veo que no tiene los atributos de una imagen.
[image: Imagen Subida]

[image: Imagen antes de subir]

El otro dato es el siguiente. Como habrán visto, en el service.ts, hago un `console.log` del `params`, que voy a enviar. Si yo copio todo el `json`, y lo pego en una petición postman, la imagen se guarda perfectamente. Entonces, al servicio llega lo que corresponde, por lo tanto deduzco que mi problema se podría encontrar a partir de la línea siguiente, donde configuro el header y hago la petición http.

Perdón por lo extenso de la pregunta, espero que puedan darme una mano.

Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Comment: para mandar ficheros desde front a back tienes que usar [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Usando_Objetos_FormData) y no json

Comment: si, hice el intento con FormData, tengo publicada la pregunta pero no llegué a una solución (no guarda la imagen). Por eso, buscando encontré a esta forma, que "al menos" llega a guardar, pero algo se pierde en el camino.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

después de casi 2 semanas de búsqueda, encontré una solución que comparto a continuación.

Primero muestro el backend, en laravel para que quede claro que debemos recibir. El método dentro del controlador queda así:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Facades\Storage;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response; 

class ProcedimientosController extends Controller
{
   public function addImage(Request $request){
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
          $image=$request->file('image');
       
          if($image){
            $image_path=$image->getClientOriginalName();
           \Storage::disk('images')->put($image_path, \File::get($image));
           
    }
         $data=array(
         
            'image'=>$image, 
            'status'=>'success'
        );
        return response()->json($data,200);
    }
}
```

Ahora desde angular, comenzamos por el component.html

```
<form #imageForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="enviarImagen()">
        <div class="col-4">
            <label for='imagen'><b>Imagen</b></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4"> <input type="file" name="imagen" #imagen="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="image" (change)="cargarImagen($event)"> </div>
        <button type="subtmit" class="btn btn-info">Agregar Imagen</button>
    </form>
```

el component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm, ReactiveFormsModule}                        from '@angular/forms';
import {FormControl,FormGroup,Validators}                                from '@angular/forms';
import { GLOBAL } from 'src/app/services/global';
import { ProcedimientosService } from 'src/app/services/procedimientos.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-nuevo',
  templateUrl: './nuevo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nuevo.component.css']
})
export class NuevoComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedFile: File=null;
constructor(
private _procedimientosService: ProcedimientosService
) { }
cargarImagen(event){
    this.selectedFile=<File>event.target.files[0]
     }

   enviarImagen(){
     this._procedimientosService.onUpload(this.selectedFile).subscribe(
       response=>{
          if(response.status=='success'){
            console.log(response);
          }
       },
       error=>{
         console.log(<any>error);
       }
     );
     
   }
}
```

y por último el service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders }  from '@angular/common/http'; 
import { Observable }               from 'rxjs';
import { GLOBAL }                   from './global';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProcedimientosService {
  public url: string;

  constructor(
    public _http: HttpClient,
  ) {
    this.url = GLOBAL.url;
   }


onUpload(file):Observable<any>{
  const fd= new FormData;
  fd.append('image',file,file.name);
  return   this._http.post(this.url+'add-image-post',fd); 
}
}
```

Nótese que GLOBAL contiene la url de mi proyecto
Como podrán observar, ni siquiera configura el header en la petición, pero funciona a la perfección.
Espero que le sirva a alguien más y agradezco muchísimo a los que aportaron con sus ideas y comentarios.

Referencia: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YkvqLNcJz3Y

Answer (score 1):

Existe un libreria en angular que es para subir archivos, es mucho mas util que utilizar la etiqueta form la libreria es esta:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-file-uploader
yo tuve problemas al instalar la version actual por lo que te recomiendo instalar la version 4.1.4 que es bastante estable, ahi podras guiarte de como instalar e implementar la libreria para que puedas subir tus imagenes

Comment: Gracias por comentar, la verdad me está costando mucho resolverlo y cualquier ayuda es valorada. Justo ayer probé también con una librería, pero era ´ngx-file-drop´ lo empaquetaba bien, pero igual no llegaba , ahora pruebo con la que me sugieres y te comento.